# How do I import web3 from esm.sh into a deno ./deps.ts file?

Tags: web3js, deno

The url https://esm.sh/web3 returns this:

```
/* esm.sh - web3@1.6.0 */
export * from "https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/web3@1.6.0/es2021/web3.js";
export { default } from "https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/web3@1.6.0/es2021/web3.js";
```

But how do I get a `web3` object?

```
import { web3 } from './deps.ts'
```

```
$ deno run --allow-all --unstable index.ts
Check file:///Users/me/www/gas/index.ts
error: TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"file:///Users/me/www/gas/deps.ts"' has no exported member 'web3'. Did you mean to use 'import web3 from "file:///Users/me/www/gas/deps.ts"' instead?
import { web3 } from './deps.ts'
         ~~~~
    at file:///Users/me/www/gas/index.ts:1:10
```

If I do: `import web3 from './deps.ts';` I get this:

```
$ deno run --allow-all --unstable index.ts
Check file:///Users/me/www/gas/index.ts
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Rand')
    at new u (https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/miller-rabin@4.0.1/es2021/miller-rabin.js:2:911)
    at https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/diffie-hellman@5.0.3/es2021/diffie-hellman.js:2:1109
    at https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/diffie-hellman@5.0.3/es2021/diffie-hellman.js:2:627
    at https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/diffie-hellman@5.0.3/es2021/diffie-hellman.js:2:11075
    at https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/diffie-hellman@5.0.3/es2021/diffie-hellman.js:2:627
    at https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/diffie-hellman@5.0.3/es2021/diffie-hellman.js:2:11635
```

Comment: The module you are trying to import is not currently compatible with Deno. As you can see in the console, the module is trying to access a property on a variable whose value is `undefined`. This is a bug in either the original source, or in the build process used by esm.sh.

Comment: which module should I file the bug with?

Comment: I'd report it to the maintainer of the module that threw the error in your log: `https://cdn.esm.sh/v54/miller-rabin@4.0.1/es2021/miller-rabin.js`. They should be able to determine if it's a problem with esm.sh or just an incompatibility with Deno.

Comment: its fixed now, but I still don't know how to import them.

Comment: If you navigate to the module and look at what it exports, then you will see what you can import.

Comment: that doesn't help